# Project Euler #4 - Largest Palindrome Project - Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, palindrome

I solved the [HackerRank version of the Largest palindrome problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler004) (similar to Project Euler 4) in Python:

> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers which is less than *N*, where 101101 < *N* < 1000000.

How can I make this more efficient? My solution keeps timing out.

Here is the Code:

```
# Find the Largest palindrome made from two three digit numbers which are less than N


# Get the input and store it in an array
def get_input():
    limit = int(input())
    limits = []

    for _ in range(limit):
        limits.append(int(input().strip()))

    return limits

# Check if palindrome or not
def is_palindrome(num):
    if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Find the Largest Palindrome
def largest_palindrome(num):
    largest = 0

    for i in range(2,999+1):
        for j in range(i+1 , 999+1):
            prod = i * j
            if is_palindrome(prod) and prod > largest and prod < num:
                largest = prod

    return largest

# Get the Limits
limits = get_input()

for limit in limits:
    print(largest_palindrome(int(limit)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [my previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145396/generalized-project-euler-4-largest-palindrome-from-product-of-two-n-digit-num/145411#145411)

- palindrome is divisible by 11
- `i` and `j` can be only odd
- reverse loops `999 -> 1` and `999 -> i - 1` - first found palindrome less than `n` is our palindrome

### Simplify code

`str(num)` is expensive, do it once

```
def is_palindrome(num):
    snum = str(num)
    return if snum == snum[::-1]
```

Instead of `prod > largest and prod < num` You can write `num > prod > largest`

Use list comprehension

```
limits = [int(input().strip()) for _ in range(limit)]
```

Comment: _To be noted_: All palindromes with an **even** number of digits are divisible by 11.